# Frames dropped when using the precompiled OpenH264 binary provided by Cisco

Tags: video-encoding, openh264

I am experiencing a problem with frames being dropped when using the precompiled OpenH264 binary provided by Cisco. However, if I compile the library myself without modifying the source, I do not have that issue.

I need to use the precompiled binary from Cisco because I'm using this for a commercial application and cannot use the open-source BSD license. I am using the ISVCEncoder's InitializeExt() call with the parameter bEnableFrameSkip set to False.

```
//My full configuration is as follows:
    encoder_->GetDefaultParams (&param);
    param.iUsageType = SCREEN_CONTENT_REAL_TIME;
    param.iRCMode = RC_BITRATE_MODE;
    param.fMaxFrameRate = framerate;
    param.iPicWidth = width;
    param.iPicHeight = height;
    param.iTargetBitrate = bitrate;
    param.bEnableDenoise = 0;
    param.bEnableFrameSkip = 0;
    param.iSpatialLayerNum = 1;

    SliceModeEnum sliceMode = SM_SINGLE_SLICE;
```

Has anyone else ran into similar problems? Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

We have to set flag bEnableFrameSkip = false.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set `param.bEnableFrameSkip = false;` to solve the frame skip problem. If you want to use `RC_BITRATE_MODE` then you have to set `param.bEnableFrameSkip = true;` as `OpenH264` doesn't support `RC_BITRATE_MODE` in frame skip disable mode.